# FixedHead in datatables doesn't work after removing pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When I delete the line “paginate”: false inside of the javascript box, 
the Fixedheader doesn’t work anymore but I don’t want pagination. Is there any way to avoid this?

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/128/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "bSort": false
   "paginate": false
} );

new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table, { "left": true } );


 $('.filterName').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var filterValue = $(this).data('filter');

    table.column(0).data().search(filterValue).draw();
});

} );
```

Comment: @amphetamachine why is this twitter-bootstrap I don't get it.

Comment: Why this was tagged 'bootstrap' I don't know.

Comment: Because it is using bootstrap for datatables.

Comment: Read the description of tags to make sure you're using the right one. The 'boostrap' tag description reads "*Not to be confused with Twitter's Bootstrap CSS framework; please use the twitter-bootstrap tag. A bootstrap is a series of procedures run when an application starts up or a request over the web is received.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant to say

> When I *put* the line “paginate”: false inside of the javascript box...

That's because you missed a comma there, should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "bSort": false,
   "paginate": false
} );
```

Comment: That was dumb, I was following datatables manual but I think that I failed to look from the javascript side. Thanks buddy.